# Using conn on view to render url

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Phoenix `1.3.0-rc` and I would like to print a url in my json return using `user_path(...)`.

My controller:

```
...
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = User.find(id)
  render(conn, "show.json", user: user)
end
...
```

My view:

```
...
def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{
    data: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "user.json"),
    links: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "links.json")
  }
end
...
def render("links.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{
    self: "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}"
  }
end
...
```

I would like to write this:

```
self: user_path(conn, :show, user.id)
```

But I get this error: `undefined function conn/0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass conn through to the view. Note that `Phoenix.Controller.render/3`
  is not the same as `Phoenix.View.render/3`. "The former expects
  a connection and relies on content negotiation while the latter is
  connection-agnostic and typically invoked from your views".<sup>1</sup>
In your controller:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = User.find(id)
  render(conn, "show.json", user: user, conn: conn)
end
```

And your view:

```
def render("show.json", %{user: user, conn: conn}) do
  %{
    data: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "user.json"),
    links: render_one(user, __MODULE__, "links.json", conn: conn)
  }
end
...
def render("links.json", %{user: user, conn: conn}) do
  %{
    self: user_path(conn, :show, user.id)
  }
end
```

1. https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L156

Comment: Great! It works perfectly! And thanks for the advise about the differences between the renders. Best!

Answer (score 2):

You can use your `Endpoint` with the same result, like:

```
alias MyAwesomeApp.Web.Endpoint
...
use_path(Endpoint, :show, user)
```